# The Emmet in VSCode does not give the full code in the boilerplate

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I am new to VSCode. I tried using the Emmet to get a HTML5 boilerplate. When I type `!` for Emmet, it does not give the full boilerplate. I got this boilerplate:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
       <html lang="en">
               <head>
                         <meta charset="UTF-8" />
                         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
               </head>

                     
               <body></body>
         </html>
```

but I expected this:

```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
             <html lang="en">
                  <head>
                        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
                        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
                        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
                        <title>Document</title>
                   </head>
                    <body></body>
                </html>
```

The `<meta https-equiv />` line is missing.

I am on Windows 7.

Comment: this is how `!` is defined for Emmet in VSC. Just write a user snippet with your required template. Or you can try to construct a custom Emmet key-sequence with this equiv tag added. You can have a look how `!` is defined in Emmet shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

Don't use any other extensions for HTML and CSS auto complete.

If you have already installed please remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and all I do is update the newest VScode version and it fixed. Now the code looks like this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```